# Building something like Omegle

Tags: php, mysql, chatroom

I want to implement a Omegle like chat system on a website, which will match up 2 people in a chatroom.

The problem is that i don't know if this is possible with just PHP and MySQL, because these are the only programming languages i have learned so far.

So the question is:

Is it possible to develop such a thing with PHP and MySQL?

if not what else is needed?

Thanks

ps. i have heard about node.js and socket.io, but would rather avoid using my time learning those two if it there's another way...

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to do the Ajax side of it.

Comment: PHP and MySQL are like [zombo.com](http://zombo.com) - everything is possible.

Comment: @MarcB - Bahahaha, what the hell was that? Not come across that one before.

Comment: @Polynomial: zombo's been around for over a decade. Still have no idea if it's got a real purpose, or is just a longstanding joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned, you could use Javascript or a library like jQuery to handle it or you could try using a pre-built chat system. [http://phpfreechat.net](http://www.phpfreechat.net/)

In terms of randomly pairing, you could store all of the active sessions in a database and randomly pair them as long as they are requesting one. Perhaps have a BOOL `is_requesting_chat` that gets set.